# How do I find out what my ssh-key's finger print is?

Tags: ssh

I ask someone for their public key, and add it to my server.

When they connect to the server for the first time, they will get the standard message in the form

```
The authenticity of host '[host]' can't be established.
# RSA key fingerprint is [fingerprint].
```

How do I find out why my key's finger print is, so I can provide it up front?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is not one "server finger print". There is one finger print for each key the server can use:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

The user can force the client to select a certain type, though:

```
ssh -o "HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,..." user@host
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. I've removed the mention of server from the question, so you can simplify the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

To get the MD5 format, like you see on GitHub, use:

```bsh
ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf <fileName>
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607295/calculate-rsa-key-fingerprint

Comment: I had to use `-E sha256` to match GitHub.